# Building app bundle for goolgeplay with cordova

Tags: android, cordova, google-play

I have cordova version 10.0.0 and the sourcecode for an app.
I can build this with cordova to iOS, this works fine!

When I want to build an app-bundle for the googleplay store. The bundle is not created but it creates an APK and googleplay does not accept that anymore. I use the commandline below (this is what i could find in the documentation).

`cordova build android --release -- --keystore=XX.keystore --storePassword=XX  --alias=XX --password=XX -- --packageType=bundle`

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure why cordova ignores the --packageType flag. As a workaround you can use android studio to generate the bundle or navigate to platforms/android and execute

```
./gradlew bundle
```

in powershell

Comment: Does the gradlew command work for you @Patrick?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, i'm not familiar with android studio, I tried but got stuck? Would you like to help to fix this? of course not for free

Comment: Did you try the command in the platforms/android folder? If so what was the response